# Bootstrap - Nav Pills only working for 1st option

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5, nav

in bootstrap nav pills work only for 1st one. I have inserted forms for each nav pill and only shows a blank page.
[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]

I have php code inside nav pills and a form. ANy fix thanks in advance

My code:
https://pastecode.io/s/3ghb2xg7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the fade class from the tab pane div.